# Determining if street address is within city limits

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am attempting to determine if a U.S. address is within city limits or not. (Another example is if an address resides within a particular county or not).

For example, we are creating a website allowing a city to sell its pet licenses. If, for example, the address is for *W. Lafayette, Indiana*, but the home is just outside of the established city limits, we want our website to be able to notify the user that they do not need to buy a pet license (otherwise when the city sees it, they need to refund that money to the pet owner).

Google Maps obviously knows city boundaries. For example, when you view W. Lafayette, IN, on the map you can see a red line and light red shading showing the city limits: ([example](https://www.google.com/maps/place/West+Lafayette,+IN/@40.4526508,-86.9518622,13z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x8812fd472165042d:0xdf75e293a8a11bef!8m2!3d40.4258686!4d-86.9080655))

**My question**: how do I determine if an address is contained within that bordered area?  (I'm hoping for perhaps the ability to send lat/lng to an API to determine if it is contained within that region... or some other ideas as to how to do this?)

**Side note**: postal code is not enough. There are many instances where an address can have a city, state, zip that is the same whether the home is in or out of city limits.

Thank you.

### Tom

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I find out if a coordinate is inside a city?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268916/can-i-find-out-if-a-coordinate-is-inside-a-city)